# Multiple specs with the same beforeEach, afterEach, etc

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm refactoring some tests/specs right now for AngularJS. Splitting up one directive spec that tested multiple directives to now have each their own spec with each directive. Combined all the directives are related to do one task.

The thing is though all those directives generally had the same beforeEach, afterEach, injector etc...

Is there a good practice for reducing code repetition with these or keep it like this?

For example...

```
describe("First Directive - ", function(){
  beforeEach(function(){
      module("fooModule");
      this.bar = bar;
  });

  inject(function($rootScope){
    this.scope = $rootScope.new();
  });

  describe("Correctly updates data", function() {
    //Does something unique
  }
});

describe("Second Directive - ", function(){
  beforeEach(function(){
      module("fooModule");
      this.bar = bar;
  });

  inject(function($rootScope){
    this.scope = $rootScope.new();
  });

  describe("Correctly updates data", function() {
    //Does something unique
  }
});
```

Comment: You could wrap the 1st/2nd Directive describes into a larger describe for the task. And then put the beforeEach at the top of that

Comment: I'm afraid you won't find the same point of view from everybody. Just bear in mind when tests include calls to "external" (to the spec file) functions, etc, they start to get complicated to understand and maintain. Maybe it's better to have some code repeated in some spec files and then that piece of code can be changed in the future for just one specific file without affecting the rest of them. It's also true that maybe a function for generating a random number could be as an utility function elsewhere outside the spec file. The final decision is up to you.